# Finding gains from the summing different phases signals

Tags: signal-processing

I have four signal which are the same frequency and different phases.
It is possible to think
S1=1kHz sine,0 degree
S2=1kHz sine,30 degree shifted
S3=1kHz sine,60 degree shifted
S4=1kHz sine,90 degree shifted
All signals are connected to a summing circuit but gains are different.
S=S1*G1 + S2*G2 + S3*G3 + S4*G4
I need to find gains for each signals by analyzing the summing signal called S.
I can think of FFT, as far as I know, FFT gives f vs phase response. But all signals have same frequency. If all signals were different frequency, it maybe possible.
Is there a method for finding gains?

Equivalent circuit of the question is given as a circuit
[image]

When all gains are equal to each other
[image]

When only gain of S4 is 2, others are 1
[image]

Comment: The only way to determine each gain S1~S4 is to Analog Mux each signal 1 at a time and measure S.  while Summing point switches do  affect signal gain, just 0 or 1

Comment: the 4 signals as you have written there are not linearly independent. For a given frequency you can find two linearly independent signals (sine and cosine aka sine shifted by 90°). To find a unique solution you need additional constrains.

One way to find one solution is by calculating the projection upon two orthonormal signals functioning as a base.

Comment: @Sider Could you explain it with an example?

Comment: As they're all at the same frequency, their sum is a sinusoid at that same frequency, so there's no way to separate them out.

Comment: When phase or amplitude of input signals is changed the phase or amplitude of output of opamp also changes. Can we formulise this behaviour as a mathametical expression?

Comment: There's an infinite number of combinations of gain and phase for two or more sinusoids at the same frequency that add up to a given sinusoid at that same frequency. So, no is the answer.